# Polynomial puzzle

Tags: polynomials, contest-math, puzzle

A nice problem that I thought I would share with you math hobbyists:

> Let $P$ be a polynomial of even degree $n$ with real coefficients and $n$ real positive roots, defined by
>   $$P(x)=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_2x^2-nx+a_0$$
>   such that $P(0)\ge 1$. Prove that $P(2)=1$.

PS: I already know a solution. I'm just sharing this for fun.

Comment: Good problem!  Thanks for the puzzle.

Comment: A nice application of the inequality between geometric and harmonic means. I am mildly concerned whether this is a good fit for Math.SE. Let's worry about that if somebody takes offence.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, personally, I browse math SE to see if there are some problems worth attacking and playing around with. I'm just handing the people like me a little treat :)

Comment: What I am concerned about is summarized [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1839/11619) and the linked threads. Not everybody will appreciate this type of questions. I judge case-by-case (yours is fine by me), but you should be prepared for diverse opinions. And. Don't continue this discussion here. It belongs in meta - not here.

Comment: Also check the assumption of your problem since they are not all necessary

Comment: Only the fact that $n$ is even isn't necessary (it can be derived from the others). I think the rest is all needed.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen There is this separate page for [puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @vrugtehagel: I think you accepted an incorrect answer. Raizen's answer looks right, but Lazy Lee's answer seems to be using the wrong formula for the coefficient of $x$.

Comment: The answer had been edited. I think it's correct now. I didn't read into the specific details, since the idea was correct, and so I assumed he had the details right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $P$ has $n$ real roots we can write 
\begin{eqnarray}
P(x) & = & x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots a_2x^2 -nx + a_0 \\
& = & (x-x_1)(x-x_2)\cdots(x-x_n) \\
& = & x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \cdots a_2x^2 +(-1)^{n-1}(\sum_{i=1}^n\prod_{j\neq i} x_j)\, x + x_1x_2\cdots x_n
\end{eqnarray}
Therefore $x_1x_2\cdots x_n = a_0$ and $(-1)^{n-1}(\sum_{i=1}^n\prod_{j\neq i} x_j) = -n$. But since $n$ is even the latter equality together with $\prod_{j\neq i}x_j = \dfrac{a_0}{x_i}$ gives $\sum_{i=1}^n\dfrac{a_0}{x_i} = n$.

By assumption $P(0)= a_0 = x_1x_2\cdots x_n\geq1$.
However, by the AM-GM inequality, $$1=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n\dfrac{a_0}{x_i}}{n}\geq a_0\left(\frac{1}{x_1x_2\cdots x_n}\right)^\frac{1}{n} = a_0^{1-\frac{1}{n}}\geq 1$$ with equality only at $\dfrac{a_0}{x_1}=\dfrac{a_0}{x_2}=\ldots=\dfrac{a_0}{x_n}$. Because equality holds, we know that all $\dfrac{a_0}{x_i}=1$ and therefore $\dfrac{a_0^n}{x_1x_2\cdots x_n} = a_0^{n-1} = 1$ which implies $a_0=1$ and hence $x_i=1.$ $P(2) = 1$ now follows directly as desired.

Comment: I did not understand the bit with $$x_1+x_2+…+x_n=n $$ It may be stupid but can you answer this?

Comment: Doesn't the $-(x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n)$ coefficient go on $x^{n-1}$?

Comment: If you're trying to use Vieta's formulas, you put the $-(x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n)$ coefficient on the wrong term. Unless you have some other justification for using that coefficient on $x$, this answer is wrong and Raizen's answer should be accepted.

Answer (score 5):

Let $ x_{1}, \dots , x_{n} $ be the positive real roots of $ P $. We have that $$ \prod_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}=(-1)^{n}a_{0}=a_{0} $$ and $$ \sum_{i=1}^{n}\prod_{j \neq i}x_{j}=(-1)^{n-1} \cdot (-n)=n $$
The last equality can be rewritten as $$ \prod_{i=1}^{n}x_{i} \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{x_{i}}=n $$
Therefore the harmonic mean of the $ x_{i}'s $ is $$ \frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{x_{i}}}=\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_{i} $$
On the other hand, we know that $$ \frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{x_{i}}} \leq (\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_{i})^{\frac{1}{n}} \leq \prod_{i=1}^{n}x_{i} $$ since  $$ \prod_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}=a_{0}=P(0) \geq 1 $$
So the harmonic mean and the geometric mean of the $ x_{i}'s$ must be equal, thus the $ x_{i}'s $ must be equal to some positive real number $ a $ and since $$ a^{n}=\frac{n}{\frac{n}{a}} $$ we conclude that $ a=1 $ is the unique root of $ P $ of multiplicity $ n $. So $ P(x)=(x-1)^{n} $ which implies that $ P(2)=1 $.